# How to get the first json code between a text including 3 json codes

Tags: javascript, json, regex, search, text

Can anyone help me with a regex to get the first json code inside a text that contains 1 or more codes?

I'm trying to use the following code: {([^']+)}
But this get all the jsons inside the code

All files that I want to get the first code in json have one or more blocks of code, and I need to get only the first one, which is the code after the word "Item Definition"

Text with 2 more jsons:

```
ItemDefinition
{ // I'm trying to get the code from here  
    "itemid": 590532217,
    "shortname": "ammo.nailgun.nails",
    "displayName": {
        "token": "ammo.nailgun.nails",
        "english": "Nailgun Nails"
    },
    "displayDescription": {
        "token": "ammo.nailgun.nails.desc",
        "english": "Standard nailgun ammunition"
    },
    "iconSprite": {
        "instanceID": 148798
    },
    "category": 8,
    "selectionPanel": 0,
    "maxDraggable": 0,
    "itemType": 1,
    "amountType": 0,
    "occupySlots": 0,
    "stackable": 64,
    "quickDespawn": false,
    "rarity": 0,
    "spawnAsBlueprint": false,
    "inventorySelectSound": {
        "instanceID": 115050
    },
    "inventoryGrabSound": {
        "instanceID": 115050
    },
    "inventoryDropSound": {
        "instanceID": 81228
    },
    "physImpactSoundDef": {
        "instanceID": 60196
    },
    "condition": {
        "enabled": false,
        "max": 0.0,
        "repairable": false,
        "maintainMaxCondition": false,
        "foundCondition": {
            "fractionMin": 1.0,
            "fractionMax": 1.0
        }
    },
    "hidden": false,
    "flags": 0,
    "steamItem": {
        "instanceID": 0
    },
    "Parent": {
        "instanceID": 0
    },
    "worldModelPrefab": {
        "guid": "d8c823436ceda0f42a4da54a972807bf"
    },
    "Traits": 8,
    "panel": {
        "instanceID": 0
    }
} // Until here

ItemModProjectile
{
    ...other json code
}
```

Comment: `s.match(/^{$([^]*?)^}$/m)[1]`

Comment: Thx so much @WiktorStribiżew sz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you can use a regex to parse JSON, it is not reliable and will fail with corner cases.

You can use this function to extract the first JSON block, and parse it:

```js
function parseFirstJson(text) {
    try {
        const regex = /^[^\{]*([\s\S]*?[\r\n]\})[\s\S]*$/;
        let obj = JSON.parse(text.replace(regex, '$1'));
        return obj;
    } catch(e) {
        // return JSON parse error
        let obj = { error: e.toString() }; 
        return obj;
    }
}

const text =`ItemDefinition
{
    "itemid": 590532217,
    "shortname": "ammo.nailgun.nails",
    "displayName": {
        "token": "ammo.nailgun.nails",
        "english": "Nailgun Nails"
    }
}

ItemModProjectile
{
    "more": "stuff"
}`;

let obj = parseFirstJson(text);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, ' '));
```

Output:

```
{
 "itemid": 590532217,
 "shortname": "ammo.nailgun.nails",
 "displayName": {
  "token": "ammo.nailgun.nails",
  "english": "Nailgun Nails"
 }
}
```

Explanation:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^\{]*` - scan until just before the first `{`
- `(` - start of capture group

  - `[\s\S]*?` - scan cautiously over all chars until:
  - `[\r\n]\}` - a `}` at the beginning of line
- `)` - end of capture group
- `[\s\S]*$` - scan over everything else until end of line

Comment: @Sasuke: Any questions? Does this fit your needs?

Comment: @Sasuke: Care to accept the answer? Help goes both ways.